# wait_event_interruptible and wake_up_interruptible take 20milliseconds to 30milliseconds

Tags: linux, v4l2

I'm working on PCIe card.When MSI interrupt is raised by PCIe card,ISR handler gets called. In ISR routine, wake_up_interruptible will wake up V4L2 thread. However time duration between wake_up_interruptible in ISR and wait_event_interruptible in v4l2 thread is range from 20 milliseconds to 30 milliseconds. Time is measured using do_gettimeofday() function from linux kernel. Below is code snippet:

File1.c

```
struct timeval t0;
irqreturn_t irq_hanlder(int irq, void *data)
{
    ...
    ...
    do_gettimeofday(&t0);
    printk("wake_up_interruptible: Time in micro_sec:%d\n",t0.tv_usec);
    atomic_set (&flag, 1);
    wake_up_interruptible(&my_wq); 
    ...
    ... 
    return IRQ_HANDLED;
}
```

File2.c

`struct timeval t1;
static int v4l2_thread(void *handle)
{
...
while(1)
    {
        ...
        wait_event_interruptible(my_wq, (atomic_read (&flag)));
        atomic_set (&flag, 0);
        do_gettimeofday(&t1);
        printk("wait_event_interruptible: Time in micro_sec:%d\n",t1.tv_usec);
        ...
    }
...
return 0;

}`

After executing above snippet code, time duration between wake_up_interruptible and wait_event_interruptible is around 20 milliseconds to 30 milliseconds.
I have used wake_up_interruptible_sync () instead of wake_up_interruptible, then also it is same behaviour.

Queries:

1) Why linux kernel is taking around 20 milliseconds to 30 milliseconds, just to wake up thread which is sleeping in file2.c ?

2) Is there is any another way of handling wake threads in linux ?

3) How to reduce this time between wake_up_interruptible and 
wait_event_interruptible ?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Kulkarni.

Comment: Is irq_handler running in interrupt context? Maybe try running a worker as a high part of irq handling and call wake_up_interruptible from there? Are you sure, that `printk` in `irq_handler` doesn't take 20 ms or 30 ms?

Comment: Is irq_handler running in interrupt context?  Yes.

Comment: Maybe try running a worker as a high part of irq handling and call wake_up_interruptible from there? I have created a work queue using INIT_WORK and called schedule_work in top half. From the bottom half I'm calling wake_up_interruptible. However, it is also taking 20 ms to 30 ms.  I don't think so printk call  will take 20ms to 30 ms. I have added printk ,just to measure time, otherwise how do i measure the time ?

Comment: I have narrow down this issue, wake_up_interruptible and wait_event_interruptible  is taking 6 micro seconds to 70 micro seconds. However, schedule_timeout_interruptible() function call in V4l2 is taking 16 ms to 21ms.